# How to combine these into a single 'msg' variable?

Tags: python, typeerror, python-3.5

Currently I have these broken down into 3 seperate 'msg's.
But I need it to be a single 'msg'.

```
    def dateDiffInSeconds(date1, date2):
      timedelta = date2 - date1
      return timedelta.days * 24 * 3600 + timedelta.seconds

    def daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(seconds):
        minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
        hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
        days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
        return (days, hours, minutes, seconds)

    injustice2 = datetime.strptime('2017-05-15 23:01:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    fridaythe13th = datetime.strptime('2017-05-25 23:01:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    shadowofwar = datetime.strptime('2017-08-21 23:01:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    now = datetime.now()

    msg = (
    '**%d** days, **%d** hours, **%d** minutes, and **%d** seconds until the release of **Injustice 2**.'
    ) % daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(dateDiffInSeconds(now, injustice2))

    msg2 = (
    '**%d** days, **%d** hours, **%d** minutes, and **%d** seconds until the release of **Friday the 13th: The Game**.'
    ) % daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(dateDiffInSeconds(now, fridaythe13th))

    msg3 = (
    '**%d** days, **%d** hours, **%d** minutes, and **%d** seconds until the release of **Middle-earth: Shadow of War**.'
    ) % daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(dateDiffInSeconds(now, shadowofwar))
```

I've tried this, but then I get "TypeError: Not enough arguments for format string". I know this has to be a simple issue that I'm not understanding well enough. Any help would be appreciated.

```
msg = (
'**%d** days, **%d** hours, **%d** minutes, and **%d** seconds until the release of **Injustice 2**.'
'**%d** days, **%d** hours, **%d** minutes, and **%d** seconds until the release of **Friday the 13th: The Game**.'
'**%d** days, **%d** hours, **%d** minutes, and **%d** seconds until the release of **Middle-earth: Shadow of War**.'
) % daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(dateDiffInSeconds(now, injustice2)), daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(dateDiffInSeconds(now, fridaythe13th)), daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(dateDiffInSeconds(now, shadowofwar))
```

Comment: I'm guessing ``daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds`` returns a tuple, so you are sending a tuple of tuples of length 3 to the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to merge the tuples generated by `daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds`.

`% (daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(dateDiffInSeconds(now, injustice2)) + daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(dateDiffInSeconds(now, fridaythe13th)) + daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(dateDiffInSeconds(now, shadowofwar)))`

Also note the enclosing `()`.

Without this you are sending a tuple of size 3 containing the values returned from `daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds`:

```
(14, 20, 5, 6), 
(24, 20, 5, 6),
(112, 20, 5, 6)
```

That is considered to be 3 values, not 12.

When we merge tuples with `+` it will be correct:

```
(14, 20, 5, 6, 24, 20, 5, 6, 112, 20, 5, 6)
```

Also note that `print` is your friend when you have issues like this.

Comment: This solved it, thank you!
I knew I was missing the obvious.

Comment: Good stuff. In the future make use of ``print`` when you have problems. That can save you so much time.

Answer (score 2):

msg = (
'**%d** days, **%d** hours, **%d** minutes, and **%d** seconds until the release of **Injustice 2**.'
'**%d** days, **%d** hours, **%d** minutes, and **%d** seconds until the release of **Friday the 13th: The Game**.'
'**%d** days, **%d** hours, **%d** minutes, and **%d** seconds until the release of **Middle-earth: Shadow of War**.'
) % (daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(dateDiffInSeconds(now, injustice2)) + daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(dateDiffInSeconds(now, fridaythe13th)) + daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(dateDiffInSeconds(now, shadowofwar)))